# Display Dialog Box once every 3 hours

Tags: javascript, html, css

Works on my website but want to it to show only once per 2-3 hours:-
https://www.helpingtechie.com

This not my code just download from a website which gave me.

I think cookies will be needed to add.

Code Used:-

```css
.guestwarn-mask{
 position:absolute;
 background:#fff;
 opacity:0.5;
 filter:alpha(opacity=50);
 z-index: 4;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.guestwarn-layout{
 -moz-transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 -ms-transform: scale(0);
 -o-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.42, 0.48, 1) 250ms;
 -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.42, 0.48, 1) 250ms;
 -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.42, 0.48, 1) 250ms;
 -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.42, 0.48, 1) 250ms;
 transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.42, 0.48, 1) 250ms;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #eee;
 background:#fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
 display:none;
 z-index:5;
}
.guestwarn-layout-animate{
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 -o-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
.guestwarn-layout-close{
 -webkit-transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(.37,-0.99,.24,.24) 100ms;
 -moz-transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(.37,-0.99,.24,.24) 100ms;
 -ms-transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(.37,-0.99,.24,.24) 100ms;
 -o-transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(.37,-0.99,.24,.24) 100ms;
 transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(.37,-0.99,.24,.24) 100ms;
 top:-300px !important;
}
.guestwarn-content{
 position:relative;
 color:#555;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.guestwarn-title{
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#eee;
 font:normal 16px Microsoft Yahei;
 color:#fff
}
.guestwarn-title span{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 padding:10px 20px;
 background:#08c;
}
.guestwarn-close{
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 background:#E04343;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:37px;
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff
}
.guestwarn-close:hover{
 opacity:0.8;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);
 }
.guestwarn-html{
 padding:50px 20px 20px 20px;
 font:normal 16px Microsoft Yahei;
 line-height: 150%;
 text-align:left;
}
.guestwarn-html a{
 color:#58f
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.helpingtechie.com/jscripts/jquery.guestwarn.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
 $.guestwarn({
  mask:true,
  height: 'auto',
  title:'Dear Guest',
  html:'If you read this, it means you are not registered. <br><a href="/member.php?action=register" target="_blank">Click here</a> to register in a few simple steps, you will enjoy all features of our Forum.',
  callback:function(){
   console.log('CALLBACKS')
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good question? What are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your "question" corectly... This can help:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.guestwarn({
            mask:true,
            height: 'auto',
            title:'Dear Guest',
            html:'If you read this, it means you are not registered. <br><a href="/member.php?action=register" target="_blank">Click here</a> to register in a few simple steps, you will enjoy all features of our Forum.',
            callback:function(){
                console.log('CALLBACKS')
            }
        });
    }, 10800000);
// 10800000 is 3 hours in miliseconds
});
```

Comment: setInterval will do guestwarn every 3 hours... And if you need guest warn only ONCE after 3 hours, use setTimeout.